# Unconstrained optimisation and Hessian Matrix solving for convexity/concavity

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, optimization, vector-analysis, hessian-matrix

Is it possible to reduce the Hessian Matrix with Gaussian elimination when we are trying to find if the function is concave or convex, assuming that all the inputs inside the Hessian matrix are scalars?

Follow up question relevant to matrices:

When trying to find the eigenvalues for the matrix, could be we reduce it first, or do we have to solve it as it is?

Thanks

Comment: The Hessian at a point is a matrix, so sure -- you could use Gaussian elimination if you want.  Though to find out if the function is concave/vex you need to know if the Hessian is positive/ negative definite and I'm not sure how Gaussian elimination helps with that.

Comment: For your followup: row reduction does not preserve eigenvalues.  So you should find the characteristic of the matrix as is.  However, if you just want to know if a matrix is positive/negative definite, you don't actually need to find all of the eigenvalues.  You could just use [Sylvester's criterion](https://www.massmatics.de/cheatsheets/#!210:Sylvesters_Criterion).

Comment: So reducing it with Gaussian first is useless. But I feel like Gaussian elimination reduces the numbers of calculations (and chance of errors) significantly. But the more pivot positions we have, the higher is the chance that we get 0 for D1, D2, and D3.

Comment: @Bye_World But we could also find the definiteness of the matrix using eigenvalues too right? If so, why do we multiply the eigenvalues together to find the determinant of the matrix when we find that the multiplicity of 2. Do we multiply them together when multiplicity is 1 and 3 as well?

Comment: For your first question: yes.  If all of the eigenvalues are positive (negative) then your matrix is positive (negative) definite.  For you second question: I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: You can do Gauss elimination, and if all pivots on the way are positive then  the matrix is positive definite. Pivots are exactly the diagonal of $D$ when you do $LDL^T$ factorisation. Note however, that positive definiteness is too much to ask, for convexity the Hessian should be positive *semi*-definite. Semidefiniteness is harder to capture in general.